# What Difference between @param And Parameters!param.Value in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, performance, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I found question in this website I search about performance report

then I see some answer they use code like this

```
="SELECT col1,col2 FROM tbl1 WHERE col1 = " & Parameters!param.Value
```

then when I see this answer I try to use in my report

my old dataset in report code like this

```
="SELECT col1,col2 FROM tbl1 WHERE col1 = @param "
```

I editd to

```
="SELECT col1,col2 FROM tbl1 WHERE col1 = '" & Parameters!param.Value & "' "
```

when I run my Report ..... it's run faster O_o?

Why after I edit dataset my Report run faster  ? 
What difference between `WHERE col1 = @param`  And `WHERE col1 = '" & Parameters!param.Value & "' "`

Thank you.

Comment: You could use profiler to see if the query that gets sent to your SQL Server is different.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same but if you are using @param instead of Parameters!param.Value will give you more flexibility. If you are using @param u need to set the parameter in the Parameters section of the dataset. But if ur directly using the parameter in ur query then u don't need to set the parameters.

[image]

Say you are having a big ad-hoc query which consists of some 1000 line of code and say some 15-20 parameters are there in that case it's easy to handle. For an example if you need to reference another parameter instead of some parameter. In that case u need to explicitly change the ad-hoc query but if u have declared @param just u need to reference to that other parameter instead.

Another scenario is there if you have changed ur parameter from single valued to multi valued then it's easy to handle. Another scenario is if ur using Stored Procedures then it's easy to map the parameters.